# how do I connect Google Actions and Watson?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, ibm-watson

I'm trying to connect Watson to Google Actions, my function is in firebase, and when I test only the connection with Watson, it works. But when I try to test it in Google console, it closes the project.

This is my code in Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = actionssdk({debug: true});
var AssistantV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v1');

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
    conv.ask('Olá, como posso lhe ajudar?');
});


app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv, input) => {
    var AssistantV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/assistant/v1');
    var assistant = new AssistantV1({
        username: '###############',
        password: '###############',
        url:'###############',
        version: '2018-07-10'
    });

    assistant.message(
    {
        workspace_id: '###############',
        input: { text: result },
        headers: {'Custom-Header': 'custom',
        'Accept-Language': 'custom'
        }
    },
    function(response) {
        conv.ask(response.output.text[0]);
    }
    );
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `assistant.message()` takes a callback function as a parameter to handle the response, but the actions-on-google library expects you to return a Promise when you are dealing with async calls. You will need to wrap this async call in a Promise and then return this Promise to the a-o-g library so it knows to wait for the callback to complete.

I haven't tested the code, but I suspect something like this should work:

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  assistant.message({
    workspace_id: '###############',
    input: { text: result },
    headers: {
      'Custom-Header': 'custom',
      'Accept-Language': 'custom'
    }
  },
  function(response) {
    conv.ask(response.output.text[0]);
    resolve();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved this problem, but now I'm receiving -> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, and I suggest you post details including your current code, what error you're getting, and where in a new Stack Overflow question. Showing the value of "response" may also be useful. If this answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated.